# Selecting multiple elements from an 2d array using a 1d array in numpy

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two arrays in numpy. The first is a 2d array, which can be thought of as a list of vectors. The second is a 1d array, which can be thought of as a list of indices into the 2d array.

I want to select elements of the 2d array using the indices of the 1d array. Right now I have been doing

```
        z=rnd.rand(2,10) # a list of 2d vectors of length 10
        z_idx=rnd.randint(2,size=z.shape[1]) #indices selecting a dimension of the 2d vector

        result=np.array([z[z_idx[i],i] for i in xrange(len(z_idx))])
```

But this is very slow.

Is there a better way to do this in numpy?

Comment: In numpy, you can select elements of an array using (bool) masks. Have you looked into that? Generally spoken, you can create such a mask from your 1D-array and then apply this mask to the 2D-array.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably the simplest method:

```
result = z[z_idx].diagonal()
```

Maybe a little more efficient would be to use `arange`:

```
result = z[z_idx, np.arange(z_idx.size)]
```

More appropriate but equivalent is `np.indices`:

```
result = z[z_idx, np.indices(z_idx.shape)[0]]
```

Comment: Note that the first method will create a `(len(z_idx), len(z_idx))` temporary array, which might be an issue.